# The following error is being displayed on Share latex. Can you help me with this problem?

Tags: xetex

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.7.12)  4 DEC 2017 17:24
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**cv.tex
(/compile/cv.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.12> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
```

Comment: there is no error in the log fragment you have posted

Comment: The error showed is this "Compile Error. Sorry, your LaTeX code couldn't compile for some reason. Please check the errors below for details, or view the raw log." It was not there earlier and there are no syntax errors.

Comment: How can we help?

Comment: What can be the possible cause of the error? It just shows compile error and the raw log is given above.

Comment: Let me rephrase my queston: As long as you don't show an actual error log, how can we help?

Comment: Perhaps you need only a bit patience. This is the place where xelatex sometimes has to recreate the font cache.

Comment: This is only the begin of the log file. Can you show us the rest, too?

Comment: No. This is the entire log file. In my window, it first says "No error, Good job" and the displays in the next line "Compile Error. Sorry, your LaTeX code couldn't compile for some reason. Please check the errors below for details, or view the raw log."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue so let me reformulate it before giving my dirty stupid fix below since I see most people commenting are thinking this post is lacking details to be answered.

I had a project that used to work, one day I come back at it and it doesn't compile. Sharelatex displays a green "No errors, good job !" and below it "Compile Error. Sorry, your LaTeX code couldn't compile for some reason. Please check the errors below for details, or view the raw log.". Sure enough I check the raw logs only to see the very same trace you gave us (I think you and I were both trying to make a CV following a template). As mentionned by David Carlisle, there is no error in this log. But it's all there is in the log.

I am pretty convinced this is a bug, because my "fix" is simply to copy the entire project as another project. Yes. "Menu" -> "Actions" -> "Copy Project". The new project that was nothing but a copy worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear your cache. If you are using Overleaf, go to the end of the page "logs and output files" (the sheet button on the right side of "Recompile"), and delete cache (the trash bin icon at the left side of "Other logs & files"). Now "Recompile" and it should work fine.